# line break conversion from html to php

Tags: php

I have html code loaded in array $gh[0] and i am coonverting it to plain text
if i compare with same text loaded into new variable it doesn't works

can someone help with the issue, what should be exact value in $a to match the content in $gh[0]

i want comparsion to be working , what will be output if $gh[0] is converted into plain text especially line break

```
<?php
    $gh[0]="Net inventory (used in)/from<br>Production Activities"
    $fg=$gh[0]->plaintext;

    $a="Net inventory (used in)/from Production Activities"

    if($a == $fg)
    { 
        echo "match";
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "No match";
    }     
 ?>
```

Comment: What? Your text doesn't makes any sense!

Comment: Hi rizier what should be there in $a to have match gh$[0] after its plain text conversion

Comment: What is this: `$fg=$gh[0]->plaintext;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about just stripping all elements from the input?

```
$gh[0]= strip_tags($gh[0]);
```

Comment: strip_tags is not working , ->plaintext is to convert html to text format

Comment: What is "plaintext"? What does the strip_tags give you?

Comment: strip_tags is working thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know what the value (of `$fg`) is, why don't you check it?

There's `echo`, `print_r` and `var_dump`.

Comment: when i use echo it shows value same as i have in $a , but match doesnt occur if the issue

Comment: does it? I guess you're watching it in the browser. browser -> view source ?